# CoreNLP Server only on localhost

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

When I start the [CoreNLP Server](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html) on Linux with:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

It is reachable at `http://localhost:9000/` (and also via `127.0.0.1:9000`). However, it is also reachable through my outside IP address, which I do not want.

I tried using the `-backends 127.0.0.1:9000` option but this does not help.

Is there a way to specify in CoreNLP Server (and not in the OS firewall rules) to only serve on localhost and 127.0.0.1, but not on any other IP address on the system, so that outside connections cannot connect to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to bind to a specific IP address through the command line arguments. In looking at the source code found [here](https://github.com/mhewett/stanford-corenlp-node/blob/master/java/src/com/lemlabs/nlp/StanfordCoreNLPServer.java#L161) you can see that it doesn't specify a bind address. By default it will bind to all addresses. Only option you have is to run a firewall of some sort and filter/block access to the port from all IP's except local ones.